# Is indexing not possible in ggplot?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df.

```
df <- structure(list(Mills = c("Mill-A", "Mill-B", "Mill-C", "Mill-D", 
"Mill-E"), Performance = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.9, 0.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

df
   Mills Performance
1 Mill-A         0.5
2 Mill-B         0.4
3 Mill-C         0.2
4 Mill-D         0.9
5 Mill-E         0.4
```

Is there a way to plot only Mill-A in x axis and Performance in y axis. I tried with below code but did not get. Can anyone please help me?

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(x=df$Mills[1],y=Performance, fill=Performance))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.5)+theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))+theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+theme(legend.position = "none")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,vjust = 1,size = 5))+theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0,vjust = 1,size = 5))
```

Reason being , I am incorporating this in R shiny application and I have filters of Mills(Mill-A,Mill-B and so on). So as per filter the plot should get ploted

I have tried with the below code in R shiny app but not working

```
selectInput("Mill","Equipment",choices = c("All","Mill-A","Mill-B","Mill-C","Mill-D","Mill-E"),selected = "All",multiple = TRUE)

output$g34 <- renderPlot({
  if (input$Mill != "All") {
     req(input$Mill)
    pd <- df %>% filter(Mills %in% input$Mill)
    g34 <- ggplot(data = pd,aes(x=Mills,y=Performance, fill=Performance))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.5)+theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))+theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+theme(legend.position = "none")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,vjust = 1,size = 5))+theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0,vjust = 1,size = 5))
  }})
plotOutput("g34")
```

Comment: Hi Dev I don't totally understand? You seem to be trying to plot a single x value against 5- y-values?

Comment: Do your filtering on the data argument, `data = df[Mills == "Mill-A"]` Though I expect for Shiny there are better options for plotting that allow you to have a drop down control the plot output, rather than needing two plots

Comment: @StephenHenderson Yes your right?

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering the data before plotting. This will plot just a single bar, so I am assuming there is more data and this is just a sample.

Here `selected_mill` will be the `input$` from your Shiny app.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  filter(Mills == selected_mill) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Mills, y = Performance, fill = Performance) + 
    (the rest of your ggplot stuff here)
```

Remember at the end of the function to also return your plot object!

```
output$g34 <- renderPlot({
  if (input$Mill != "All") {
     req(input$Mill)
    pd <- df %>% filter(Mills %in% input$Mill)
    g34 <- ggplot(plot things)

    return(g34)
  }})
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried similar to this in R shiny app but not working. I have added the code at the end. PLease let me know what wrong I am doing

Comment: All I can think of from just looking at that is maybe `Mills` is a factor and not a character column? I would check that to see. Maybe that is affecting filtering.

Comment: No Its a character. I checked with ````class(df$Mills)````

Comment: But the code is correct right? I mean the shiny code? Could you please help me in this. I am pretty sure the code is correct

Comment: I am not sure what this is doing: `req(input$Mill)`. I always find Shiny code a bit tough to debug.

Comment: that is required since I am using that filter in my output

Comment: Ah. You are not returning the plot. You are saving it into the object `g34`, but never actually have the function return it!

Comment: Awesome and I got it, Thanks a lot.